# Develop a VBScript version of the "Guess a Number" game

Tags: vbscript

I've searched at StackOverflow and saw that implementation of the "Guess a Number" game was discussed previously, here for instance: [How to create a number guessing game in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688100/how-to-create-a-number-guessing-game-in-javascript).  However, my challenge is to do this using VBScript.

I am new to programming and I have been working on this code for tens of hours to no avail.  For some reason, the code skips portions and has an issue looping. Specifically, the code (line 45) asks for the user to input their guess. Once they do that, the code skips the code at line 49 and onward, crashing the script. Script is supposed to execute `if`-`then` sequence (lines 48-68) to test user input with against random number while providing them with too high or low feedback.

How do I fix that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
'Initialization Section

Option Explicit

Const cGreetingMsg = "Pick a number between 1 - 100"

Dim intUserNumber, intRandomNo, strOkToEnd, intNoGuesses, strOkToEnd1

Randomize
intRandomNo = FormatNumber(Int((100 * Rnd) + 1))
intNoGuesses = 0

function GetPlayersName()
GetPlayersName = InputBox("What is your first name? ")


'Main Processing Section


End Function


select case strOkToEnd

    case 1 
    If FormatNumber(intUserNumber) < intRandomNo Then 

          'Test to see if the user's guess was too low
        MsgBox "Your guess was too low. Try again", ,cGreetingMsg
        End If 

    case 2

    If FormatNumber(intUserNumber) > intRandomNo Then
        MsgBox "Your guess was too high. Try again", , cGreetingMsg
        End If 

'Loop until either the user guesses correctly or the user clicks on Cancel
End Select



'Generate a random number

Do Until strOkToEnd = "yes"
  'Prompt user to pick a number
  intUserNumber = InputBox("Type your guess:", GetPlayersName, cGreetingMsg)
  intNoGuesses = intNoGuesses + 1
    'See if the user provided an answer  
    If Len(intUserNumber) <> 0 Then
        'Make sure that the player typed a number
    If IsNumeric(intUserNumber) = True Then
    Else
    If IsNumeric(intUserNumber) = False Then
    MsgBox "Sorry.  You did not enter a number.  Try Again."
    strOkToEnd = "yes"
    'Test to see if the user's guess was correct
    If FormatNumber(intUserNumber) = intRandomNo Then
          MsgBox "Congratulations! You guessed it. The number was " & _
          intUserNumber & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "You guessed it " & _
          "in " & intNoGuesses & " guesses.", ,cGreetingMsg
          strOkToEnd = "yes"
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
Exit Do 
Loop
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'd recommend you to try to clarify the actual issue, "the code skips portions and has an issue looping", which is not quite clear yet. Also, please take the tour (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask so that others will be glad to help you. You have a very long intro, so I proposed some edits to it; I think, you can improve it further. Best regards.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  Specifically, the code (line 45) asks for the user to input their guess.  Once they do that, the code skips the code at line 49 and onward, crashing the script.  Script is supposed to execute if then sequence (lines 48-68) to test user input with against random number while providing them with too high or low feedback.

Comment: Right, it is generally recommended to add new details to the post directly, so that guys who see your question for the first time don't need to read the comments to get what's going on (I've suggested another edit). But I have to admit: nobody will count lines in this context, so you'd better specify what those lines you're discussing contain. Another note: is that ok that you use both `function` and `Function` in your script? (I have no experience with VBScript)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with general recommendations:

- When you encounter a problem with your code, mentally step through and consider what will happen at each line. Follow the flow of execution.
- When you aren't sure what's going on, you can throw in a MsgBox statement to print out a variable and see its value.
- Try to write out the steps you need in comments or own paper first. It looks like you might have had comments to guide you, but it also looks like these weren't necessarily updated as you made changes.
- When you do write your code, try to indent consistently, so you can tell when you're inside of a loop or an if, etc. (To be fair, this may just have been from copying the code into your question)

On to more specifics. Start by thinking about the minimum things you want to get done. You want this:

```
'Get a random number
'Loop until user is correct or wants to exit
    'Ask user to input a number
    'Check the number against your randomly selected number
    'Output result
```

Your Select statement is outside of the loop entirely, and the value it selects from is actually not initialized at all when you get there. You also don't have a case else, so this section will never do anything. strOkToEnd looks like it's mainly used as an exit flag, and only ever set to "yes" anyway, so I'm not sure why you're looking for it to be 1 or 2 here. (For a flag like that, a boolean value would be a better choice.) Your checks for the user's number being too high and too low are here too, so those lines will be missed.

The loop starts off nicely. Only problem I see with the start of the loop, is that GetPlayerName is called at the beginning so that every iteration would ask for the user's name. You should call that outside the loop and save the value. The end of the loop is a problem though. The last line is "Exit Do", meaning the loop will never execute more than once.

When you start processing the input though, things get messy. Notice that nesting the if statements several layers makes things complicated. Every level of nesting increases complexity, so try and minimize that. To do that, you can use tools like "AND" or "ElseIf ... Then".

The first If checks input length not = 0. If that length is 0, you do nothing. Everything else is nested inside this if, so entering nothing skips it all. It's fine to include something like this, but it's best to make sure the happy path through the program works first. If you do find a problem with input, try to give error output to let the user know, and make sure the loop still takes them back.

So let's say the input length isn't 0, so we get inside that block. The next check is for IsNumeric. If input is a number, you do nothing. That's a problem. You want the comparison's here, inside the "If IsNumeric(intUserNo) = True Then" block. Also be aware that if a function returns True or False, you don't want to include the " = True" part, it's enough to say "If IsNumeric(intUserNo) Then".

When not numeric, the function goes into the Else as it should. Inside this Else, the "If IsNumeric(intUserNumber)" check doesn't do anything but add complexity. Inside that, you output the correct error message and set the exit flag, but then (still inside the block that executes when input is not numeric) you check to see if their number matches yours.

Here's a stripped down version of the guess a number game in VBS:

```
Option Explicit

Dim intUserNo, intRandomNo, boolExit

'Get random number
Randomize
intRandomNo = Int((100 * Rnd) + 1)

'Loop until number is guessed
boolExit = False
Do Until boolExit
    'Prompt user for number
    intUserNo = InputBox("Guess a number:")
    intUserNo = cInt(intUserNo)

    'See if user number matches the random number
    If intUserNo = intRandomNo Then
        MsgBox "Congratulations! You guessed it!"
        boolExit = True 
    ElseIf intUserNo > intRandomNo Then
        MsgBox "Too high"
    Else
        MsgBox "Too low"
    End If
Loop
```

Even if overdue though, it's still homework. So I'll leave the extra features for you to work out.

Hope that helps out.

Answer (score -1):

This is in Visual Studio 2017  and it runs in console just paste all in a Console project.

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    Dim displayMenu As Boolean = True
    While (displayMenu)
        displayMenu = MainMenu()

    End While
End Sub


Function MainMenu() As Boolean
    Console.Clear()
    Console.WriteLine("Choose an option: ")
    Console.WriteLine("1 - Print Numbers")
    Console.WriteLine("2 - Guessing Game")
    Console.WriteLine("3 - Exit")

    Dim result As String = Console.ReadLine()

    If result = "1" Then
        Return PrintNumbers()
    ElseIf result = "2" Then
        Return GussingGame()
    ElseIf result = "3" Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If

End Function

Function PrintNumbers() As Boolean

    Console.Clear()
    Console.WriteLine("Type a number: ")
    Dim result As Integer = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
    Dim counter As Integer = 1
    While counter < result + 1
        Console.Write(counter)
        Console.Write(" - ")
        counter += 1
    End While
    Console.ReadLine()
    Return True

End Function

Function GussingGame() As Boolean

    Console.Clear()
    Console.WriteLine("Type a number: ")
    Dim random As New Random()
    Dim randomNumber As Integer = random.Next(1, 11)
    Dim guesses As Integer = 0
    Dim incorrect As Boolean = True

    Do While incorrect = True
        Console.Write(" Guess a number between 1 and 10:")
        Dim result As String = Console.ReadLine()
        guesses += 1
        If result = randomNumber.ToString() Then
            incorrect = False


        ElseIf result < randomNumber Then
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong. too low")

        ElseIf result > randomNumber Then
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong. too high")

        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong")
        End If
    Loop

    Console.WriteLine("Correct! It took you {0} guesses.", guesses)
    Console.ReadLine()
    Return True

End Function
```

End Module

'I am teaching myself and figured out the too high too low but with 
'help looking at what others wrote. there is probably an easier way but
'I hope it helps. I got most this off of Microsoft Virtual Academy 
'https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/visual-basic-fundamentals-for-'absolute-beginners-16507?l=sg5H0OKbC_8306218965

Comment: Not VBScripts and compares Strings, not Numbers.